# 96 Suburban intermittent falter/stall immediate restart

Tags: engine, stall, intermittent-problems

96 GMC K1500 Suburban. Falters/stalls. Intermittent. So far low speed/parking lot acceleration from stop. Also deceleration low speed as in coming to stop. Radio cuts in and out around the time of the event. First happened under damp conditions but has happened during dry conditions as well. Restarts immediately if it stalls and runs well and smoothly otherwise giving no indication of problem.Have cleaned corrosion from battery terminal but still occurring. Acts as though key were backed off briefly.

Comment: This very well could be the ignition switch going bad, especially if you hang any weight off your keys.

Comment: Because it happens at low speeds exclusively, check your idle air control valve.